# Why is Sitecore CDP Audience Sync failing?

Tags: segmentation, cdp

I am trying to export a segment on a regular schedule using Sitecore CDP Audience Sync. What are some common issues that can cause this to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are some common causes of a failing audience sync:

**Data is not mapped correctly**

To ensure that the data you are trying to export exists and is mapped as expected, test your flow using workbench https://app.boxever.com/#/flows/workbench. Workbench also contains a section at the bottom called debug context, this section displays the data model that is being used for the Audience Sync.

Please note that this is the URL for the workbench if the data centre for your tenant is in Europe. If the data centre for your tenant is in APJ or the US, then the root of the URL above needs to be updated to match the URL when you are using the platform (e.g. https://app-us.boxever.com/#/flows/workbench for a US tenant).

**Data is missing for one guest in the segment**

After the Audience Sync runs a success and an error report file will be available in the platform when you open the Audience Sync. In the error report file, details of any errors will be included.

**Segment does not exist**

Ensure that the segment you are using the Audience Sync exists and is Live. Batch Segments are created and updated every 24 hours. Therefore after creating your segment, you will need to wait 24 hours until this segment can be exported. The date of when your segment will be updated can be seen in the details section of the segment in the platform. Your segment is ready to be exported when the status moves from Scheduled to Live.

For details on batch segmentation see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/introducing-batch-segmentation.html

**Dataset date is incorrect**

When triggering an Audience Sync manually, the dataset date needs to be included in the request. The dataset date needs to be for a date that the segment exists and has been built.

For details on triggering the Audience Sync see: https://sitecore.cdpknowledgehub.com/docs/batch-flows-best-practices. Here is a link to a github repo with a postman collection for triggering Audience Sync through the endpoints: https://github.com/soreilly6/TechnicalTrainingCourse/blob/main/Batch%20Imports%20%26%20Audience%20Sync.postman_collection.json